# Can't clone Google Cloud Repository in Compute Engine

Tags: node.js, google-compute-engine, google-source-repositories

I'm trying to set up a Node project in Google Compute Engine, following this guide: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/getting-started-on-compute-engine

Everything runs fine on the startup script, until line 27:

```
git clone https://source.developers.google.com/p/${PROJECTID}/r/${REPOSITORY} /opt/app/new-repo
```

When script tries to clone the repo, I get a few errors in log:

`INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument`

`message: "Invalid authentication credentials. Please generate a new identifier: https://source.developers.google.com/new-password"`

`fatal: unable to access 'https://source.developers.google.com/<path-to-repo>': The requested URL returned error: 400`

What could be the cause of this error, and how can I fix it? I've tried to research cloning authentication, but haven't found anything related to scripts. I visited the new-password link, and tried to execute the gitcookie command in server, but it didn't help.

Startup script I use is exactly like [in guide](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/getting-started-on-compute-engine#use_a_startup_script_to_initialize_an_instance):

```
set -v


# Talk to the metadata server to get the project id
PROJECTID=$(curl -s "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/project-id" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google")
REPOSITORY="new-repo"

# Install logging monitor. The monitor will automatically pick up logs sent to
# syslog.
curl -s "https://storage.googleapis.com/signals-agents/logging/google-fluentd-install.sh" | bash
service google-fluentd restart &

# Install dependencies from apt
apt-get update
apt-get install -yq ca-certificates git build-essential supervisor

# Install nodejs
mkdir /opt/nodejs
curl https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.12.0/node-v8.12.0-linux-x64.tar.gz | tar xvzf - -C /opt/nodejs --strip-components=1
ln -s /opt/nodejs/bin/node /usr/bin/node
ln -s /opt/nodejs/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm

# Get the application source code from the Google Cloud Repository.
# git requires $HOME and it's not set during the startup script.
export HOME=/root
git config --global credential.helper gcloud.sh
git clone https://source.developers.google.com/p/${PROJECTID}/r/${REPOSITORY} /opt/app/new-repo

# Install app dependencies
cd /opt/app/new-repo
npm install

# Create a nodeapp user. The application will run as this user.
useradd -m -d /home/nodeapp nodeapp
chown -R nodeapp:nodeapp /opt/app

# Configure supervisor to run the node app.
cat >/etc/supervisor/conf.d/node-app.conf << EOF
[program:nodeapp]
directory=/opt/app/new-repo
command=npm start
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=nodeapp
environment=HOME="/home/nodeapp",USER="nodeapp",NODE_ENV="production"
stdout_logfile=syslog
stderr_logfile=syslog
EOF

supervisorctl reread
supervisorctl update

# Application should now be running under supervisor
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this issue is due to the caller not having permissions to the repository, I recommend you to check the account you are using to run this command has the required permissions to interact with Source Repositories.

If missing, I would suggest adding the role *roles/source.admin* to your account, using [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access#granting-console), and then try to run the command again.

Comment: Thank you, it was a permission issue indeed.